# Schwarz's Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm currently going through Spivak's Calculus(3rd edition) and I'm almost certain that I have found a mistake in one of the exercises. In Chapter 1 Exercise 19 (a), the *Schwarz Inequality* is given by:

$x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 \leq \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$

Prove that if $x_1 = \lambda y_1$ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$ for **some** number $\lambda$ then equality holds in the Schwarz inequality.

My proof so far:

$x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 = \lambda y_1 y_1 + \lambda y_2 y_2 = \lambda y_1^2 + \lambda y_2^2 = \lambda (y_1^2 + y_2^2)$.

So here's where the trouble starts for me: $(y_1^2 + y_2^2) \geq 0$, but we didn't make any assumptions for $\lambda$. In order for $\lambda (y_1^2 + y_2^2) = \sqrt{\lambda^2 (y_1^2 + y_2^2)^2}$,

$\lambda \geq0$  must hold. I think that the problem statement is wrong and that $\lambda$ must be positive.Is this really the case or am I wrong?

Comment: I think the inequality should read as $|x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2| \leq \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$.

Comment: You're right. If $\lambda$ is negative, then the negative of LHS equals RHS.

Comment: Yes, the absolute value is missing -- should be $\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right| \leq \sqrt{\|x\|}\sqrt{\|y\|}$.

Comment: In the Fourth Edition, it reads. ... if ${x}_{1} = \lambda  {y}_{1}$ and  ${x}_{2} = \lambda {y}_{2}$ for some number $\lambda \ge 0$, then  ......