# Spivak Chapter 1, Problem 19(a)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

Per Spivak

> The great granddaddy of all inequalities is the *Schwarz inequality* $${x}_{1}{y}_{1}+{x}_{2}{y}_{2} \le \sqrt{{x}_{1}^{2} + {x}{_2}^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}{_2}^{2}}$$

> Prove that if ${x}_{1} = \lambda {y}_{1}$ and ${x}_{2} = \lambda {y}_{2}$ for some number $\lambda \ge 0$, then equality holds in the Schwarz inequality.

There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936786/schwarzs-inequality), but it seems to follow the pattern elsewhere of simply substituting on both sides of the given inequality, and changing the $\le$ to an $=$, unless I am misunderstanding it. Amusingly, having invested in Spivak's answer book, his answer is "*The proofs for .... are straightforward*" :-)

Here is my attempt.

Given ${x}_{1} = \lambda y_{1}$ and ${x}_{2} = \lambda y_{2}$ then
$$\sqrt{{x}_{1}^{2} + {x}_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}} = \sqrt{(\lambda {y}_{1})^{2} + (\lambda {y}_{2})^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\lambda^{2} {y}_{1}^{2} + \lambda^{2} {y}_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\lambda^{2}( {y}_{1}^{2} +  {y}_{2}^{2})}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\lambda^{2}}\sqrt{( {y}_{1}^{2} +  {y}_{2}^{2})}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$$  Note: $\sqrt {\lambda^{2}} = \lambda \iff \lambda \ge 0 $ as asserted in the problem.
$$=\lambda ({y}_{1}^{2} +  {y}_{2}^{2})$$
$$=\lambda {y}_{1}^{2} +  \lambda{y}_{2}^{2}$$
$$=\lambda {y}_{1}{y}_{1} +  \lambda{y}_{2}{y}_{2}$$
$$=(\lambda {y}_{1}){y}_{1} +  (\lambda{y}_{2}){y}_{2}$$
$$=x_{1}{y}_{1} +  x_{2}{y}_{2}$$

Comment: It's almost complete: where did you use the fact that $\lambda\geq 0$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo, $\sqrt{\lambda^{2}}$ =$\lambda$ iff $\lambda\ge 0$.

Comment: @RAHUL yes I'm aware, I just wanted OP to be explicit about where the various hypotheses are being used.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, I did wonder about that. Maybe I need to add a small annotation to the line after $\sqrt {\lambda^{2}}$? (as suggested by @Rahul) ?? But, not quite sure how to add this to the proof?

Comment: Edited my answer….but it seems awkward.

Comment: Your problem concerning the inequality can be fixed by placing modulus signs like this,$|x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}|$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the exact problem should be like this,
$$|x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}|\le \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}}$$
*If $x_{1}=\lambda y_1$ and $x_2=\lambda y_2$*
Now it's obvious that,
$$|x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}|\le |x_{1}y_{1}|+|x_{2}y_{2}|$$
... After following what op done in the description of the problem, we are left with,
$$|x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}|\le |x_{1}y_{1}|+|x_{2}y_{2}|\le \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}}$$
Which implies that,
$$|x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}|\le \sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I am never sure whether an answer should be in the exact form in which the problem was presented, but your answer makes perfect sense.